# jQuery tabs - Selecting all menu ul elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm new to using jQuery and my first bigger improvement to static website is a jQuery tabs which let's me switch main page divs on sidebar and topbar menus. 
I can't seem to get the script to work with every nav class element. 
As of right now it's working on said elements: Poradnik 1,2,3,4 and I'd also want them to work on Strona główna, Spis treści, Poradniki and O autorze. Basically all elements that are located under nav.
What should I change? Could anyone help me out with it? Thank you.

Below I'll put the code for the required elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('ul.nav ul li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.nav ul li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 }) 
})
```

```css
.tab-content{
 display: none;
 padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current{
 display: inherit;
}
.topmenu {
 width: 875px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 90px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.topmenu ul {
 padding: 25px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 height: 25px;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav li a:hover { 
 width: 120px;  
 height: 25px;
 background: #D2E2FF;
 color: #000;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 4px;
}

.topmenu ul.nav li:hover ul {
 left: 0px;
 top: 38px;
 padding: 0px;
 border:solid 1px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav li:hover ul li a {
 padding: 6px;
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-top-color: #000;
 border-right-color: #000;
 border-bottom-color: #000;
 border-left-color: #000;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
}

ul.nav {
 list-style: none; 
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.nav li {
float:left;
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited { 
 display: block; 
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 3px;
}

ul.nav li a:hover { 
 background-color: #D2E2FF;
 color: #000;
 border: solid 1px black;
 padding: 2px;
}

ul.nav ul a:hover { 
 background-color: #D2E2FF;
 color: #000;
 padding: 3px;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 border-bottom-style: none;
 border-left-style: none;
}

ul.nav li a:focus, ul.nav li a:active {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

ul.nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 top: -9999px;
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul.nav li:hover {
 position: relative;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul {
 left: 30px;
 top: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: solid 1px;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul li a {
 padding: 3px;
 width:300px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul li a:hover {
 background: #D2E2FF;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="strona_glowna"><a href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="spis_tresci"><a href="#">Spis treści</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Poradniki</a>
    <ul>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_1"><a href="#">Poradnik 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_2"><a href="#">Poradnik 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_3"><a href="#">Poradnik 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_4"><a href="#">Poradnik 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="o_autorze"><a href="#">O autorze</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div id="strona_glowna" class="tab-content current">
  <h1>Strona główna</h1>
  <p>Strona główna</p>
 </div>
  
 <div id="spis_tresci" class="tab-content">
  <h1>Spis treści</h1>
  <p>Spis treści</p>
 </div>
  
 <div id="poradnik_1" class="tab-content">
  <h1>Poradnik 1</h1>
  <p>Poradnik 1</p>
 </div>
  
 <div id="poradnik_2" class="tab-content">
  <h1>Poradnik 2</h1>
  <p>Poradnik 2</p>
 </div>
  
 <div id="poradnik_3" class="tab-content">
  <h1>Poradnik 3</h1>
  <p>Poradnik 3</p>
 </div>
  
 <div id="poradnik_4" class="tab-content">
  <h1>Poradnik 4</h1>
  <p>Poradnik 4</p>
 </div>
  
 <div id="o_autorze" class="tab-content">
  <h1>O autorze</h1>
  <p>O autorze</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work now. The problem is that when you click on one of the inner `<li>`'s, you are also clicking on one of the *outer* `<li>`'s. To avoid this, use this JQuery/JavaScript function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.nav li:not(.innerNav)').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('.ul.nav > li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

and give the `<li>` with the `<ul>` inside, the class `innerNav`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.nav li:not(.innerNav)').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('.ul.nav > li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
.topmenu {
  width: 875px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.topmenu ul {
  padding: 25px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav li a:hover {
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #D2E2FF;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav li:hover ul {
  left: 0px;
  top: 38px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.topmenu ul.nav li:hover ul li a {
  padding: 6px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
}
ul.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.nav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3px;
}
ul.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #D2E2FF;
  color: #000;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
}
ul.nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: #D2E2FF;
  color: #000;
  padding: 3px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
}
ul.nav li a:focus, ul.nav li a:active {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: -9999px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.nav li:hover {
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul {
  left: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul li a {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: #D2E2FF;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="strona_glowna">
        <a href="#">Strona główna</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="spis_tresci">
        <a href="#">Spis treści</a>
      </li>
      <li class="innerNav">
        <a href="#">Poradniki</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_1">
            <a href="#">Poradnik 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_2">
            <a href="#">Poradnik 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_3">
            <a href="#">Poradnik 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="poradnik_4">
            <a href="#">Poradnik 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="o_autorze">
        <a href="#">O autorze</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content current" id="strona_glowna">
    <h1>Strona główna</h1>
    <p>Strona główna</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="spis_tresci">
    <h1>Spis treści</h1>
    <p>Spis treści</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="poradnik_1">
    <h1>Poradnik 1</h1>
    <p>Poradnik 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="poradnik_2">
    <h1>Poradnik 2</h1>
    <p>Poradnik 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="poradnik_3">
    <h1>Poradnik 3</h1>
    <p>Poradnik 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="poradnik_4">
    <h1>Poradnik 4</h1>
    <p>Poradnik 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="o_autorze">
    <h1>O autorze</h1>
    <p>O autorze</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Darthenn How's my answer?

Comment: How is `<a href="#">Poradniki</a>` going to trigger that function if it's not in a `<li>`?

Comment: @James It's not supposed to. The `<a>`'s inside the `<ul>` next to this `<a>` tag you're talking about, however, are. Have a look at the snippet.

Comment: I can't do that because I'm using them to have a dropdown menu items. The snippet doesn't have all the code for it to look as a dropdown.

Comment: I just added the required css for it to look as a dropdown

Comment: If you're trying to prevent a click on an inner thing from triggering a click on an outer thing, check [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

select other li like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.nav li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        if(typeof(tab_id) != 'undefined'){  
            $('ul.nav li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        }      
    })  
})
```

simply follow the chain in your HTML for jquery selectors.

demo fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/6y7z1Lmq/1/

Comment: If I exchange "ul.nav ul li" with "ul.nav li" it then only works for "Strona główna, Spis treści etc." but not the Poradnik1,2,3,4.

Comment: do this  $('ul.nav li, ul.nav ul li')

Comment: I've just changed to ul.nav li, ul.nav ul li and it still only works for the elements that are higher ("Strona główna etc.").

Comment: can you share link to website if possible?

Comment: I'm running it locally.

Comment: `ul.nav li` should be the only selector you need as evidenced [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsfmr075/)

Comment: @Darthenn check my solution in fiddle.